# How to enable or disable authentication using config parameter or variable?

Tags: c#, authentication, servicestack, app-config, anonymous

I would like to implement a switch in configuration that allows to enable (`windowsAuth=true`) or disable Windows authentication (`windowsAuth=false`), so it will be used as anonymous.

How to achieve that in possible easy way or maybe there is something already ready to use?

I tried to set the following to disable.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode = "None" />
    <authorization >
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

However, the prompt for user/pw window still appears upon I click for Try Request in SwaggerUI.

Below the code

```
private void SetupPlugins(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

    container.RegisterAs<OrmLiteCacheClient, ICacheClient>();

    container.Resolve<ICacheClient>().InitSchema();

    container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
        new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

    container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();

    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[] {
            new AdGroupAuthProvider(container.Resolve<IActiveDirectoryAuthHelper>(),
            GlobalConfiguration.Instance.AllowedActiveDirectoryGroup)
        }
    ));
}

internal class AdGroupAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryAuthHelper _adLoggingHelper;
    private readonly string _loggedUserAdGroup;

    public AdGroupAuthProvider(IActiveDirectoryAuthHelper loggingHelper, string loggedUserAdGroup)
    {
        _adLoggingHelper = loggingHelper;
        _loggedUserAdGroup = loggedUserAdGroup;
    }
    public override bool Authenticate(IServiceBase loggingServiceBase, string userName, string password)
    {
        return _adLoggingHelper.HasUserAssignedGroup(userName, password, _loggedUserAdGroup);
    }
}

[Authenticate(ApplyTo.Get)]
[Route("/someRoute", "GET")]
public class someRequest { ...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to quickly enable/disable authentication. We can resolve it by adding **Authenticate attributes** dynamically. This can also be easily change to use different auth provider.

So, we can easily determine by this AuthenticateAttribute if Request A, B or C must have enabled authentication or not.

```cs
private void SetupPlugins(Container container, ILog log)
{ ...
    bool activeDirectoryAuthentication = ToBoolean(GlobalConfiguration.Instance.ActiveDirectoryAuthentication);
    ApplyTo applyTo = ApplyTo.Get;
    if (!activeDirectoryAuthentication) applyTo = ApplyTo.None;

    typeof(RequestA).AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute(applyTo));
    typeof(RequestB).AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute(applyTo));
    typeof(RequestC).AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute(applyTo));
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it isn't possible to disable Windows Authentication in code at runtime as it's triggered by IIS/ASP.NET before the request reaches ServiceStack and your ASP.NET Application.

Comment: I conducted few adhoc test and I think I achieved demanded effect. When I removed attribute `[Authenticate(ApplyTo.Get)]` from the request class I was able to Try the request and prompt window has not appeared. Is it possible that one time the Authenticate  attribute could be set another time not (depending on the variable). To clarify it would be enough for me to determine the auth before or during starting the windows service.

Comment: @essential If that's the case the 401 came from ServiceStack, an easy way to bypass Authentication is to [enable an AuthSecret](https://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#authsecret) which will let you make authenticated requests as an Admin using `?authsecret=...` on the queryString.

Comment: while you answered I was edited the comment above. thanks I will read that.

Comment: I added `SetConfig(new HostConfig { AdminAuthSecret = "secretz" });` However prompt window still appearing. Could you please provide step by step how to achieve that based on the above code?

Comment: @essential There are no steps, adding `?authsecret=secretz` to the queryString should let you call an `[Authenticate]` protected Services for normal ServiceStack Auth Providers, but Windows Auth can enforce their own Authentication before the Request reaches ServiceStack. Note `BasicAuthProvider` is for HTTP Basic Auth, here's an example of an [ASP.NET Windows Auth Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AspNetWindowsAuthProvider.cs) implementation.

Comment: But in the doc, there is info that I can use this without adding the string: _You can use Config.AdminAuthSecret to specify a special string to give you admin access without having to login by adding ?authsecret=xxx to the query string, e.g:_
`SetConfig(new HostConfig { AdminAuthSecret = "secretz" });`

Comment: @essential  you need to configure an authsecret in order to be able to use it, it’s not a substitute for not providing an authsecret, it’s to allow it.

Comment: could you provide any example?

Comment: @essential There's nothing more to it than adding `?authsecret=...` to the queryString. The [mvcauth](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcauth) and [mvcidentity](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) project templates have examples of calling protected Services using the configured AdminAuthSecret.

Comment: I checked that when I change the attribute in Request: from `[Authenticate(ApplyTo.Get)]` to `[Authenticate(ApplyTo.None)]` then prompt window does not appear and status is 200. Could we change this attribute at first running of the service or maybe just disable whole authentication at service starting? On QA environment this service currently doesn't have authentication and I'd like to add possibility to enable AD auth by changing config and restarting service (if required).

Comment: @essential We’d never do anything as unsafe as temporarily disabling Authentication. No requests are made “when starting”, Startup occurs when the App is initialized before any requests are made, when the 1st Request it’s considered “at runtime”. As your custom AuthProvider implementation is an [IAuthWithRequest](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers) you have control in your Authenticate() method whether to authenticate a request at runtime or not, otherwise don’t use the [Authenticate] attr, validate Auth in your own service.

Comment: It's not about security matter right now. It is just about ability of enabling or disabling auth in the config.